# Development workflow with issues, pull request and CI/CD

Tags: git, continuous-integration, workflow, pipeline, continuous-deployment

I'm learning about CI/CD, but something is not clear:

Following the Git Flow structure, see the below example, which is in chronology sort:

**For new feature #1:**

**Programmer:**

`git checkout -b feature/1
git add .
git commit -m "something"
git push origin feature/1
On the browser and create a pull request from feature/1 to dev "Closes #1"`

**Gitlab-CI/Jenkins, others:**

`start the pipeline cloning the project
git checkout feature/1
execute the test jobs
if all succeed:
  enable the merge request button
else:
  disable the merge request button`

**Code Reviewer:**

`see the pull request
authorize the pull request (click in the merge quest button)`

**Gitlab-CI/Jenkins, others:**

`start the pipeline cloning the project
git checkout -b release-123456 feature/1
update the config files, with the new version number
git commit -m "Update version to 123456"
execute the job package
if the job succeed:
  git checkout feature/1
  git merge release-123456
  git push origin feature/1
  git checkout dev
  git merge release-123456
  git push origin dev
  deploy to staging
else:
  git checkout feature/1
  git branch -D release-123456`

**For production release**

**Programmer:**

`create a pull request from dev to master`

**Gitlab-CI/Jenkins, others:**

`start the pipeline cloning the project
git checkout dev
execute the test jobs
if all succeed:
  enable the merge request button
else:
  disable the merge request button`

**Code Reviewer:**

`see the pull request
authorize the pull request (click in the merge quest button)`

**Gitlab-CI/Jenkins, others:**

`start the pipeline cloning the project
git checkout -b release-7890 dev
update the config files, with the new version number
git commit -m "Update version to 7890"
execute the job package
if the job succeed:
  git checkout dev
  git merge release-7890
  git push origin dev
  git checkout master
  git merge dev
  git push origin master
  deploy to production
else:
  git checkout dev
  git branch -D release-7890`

- This workflow is correct?
- The executed actions are executed by the correct actors?
- How is the workflow in your jobs?